# How to replace specific field with sed between two paterns with other file content?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, ansible, scripting

I want that file :

```
#ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 [win] #s1 192.168.1.148 #s2
```

to be like this :

```
#ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 [win] #s1 127.0.0.1 #s2
```

Im typing :

```
sed -e '/#s1/,/#s2/c\#s1\n127.0.0.12\n\#s2' hosts
```

OK, but I want the address from **another file** called tmp_ip :
10.0.0.1 for example but it can be **any address** present in it.

What could i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E "s/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+?)+/$(cat tmp_ip)/" input_file
#ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 [win] #s1 127.0.0.1 #s2
```

Or if the pattern must be matched

```
$ sed -E "s/(#s1 )[^#]*/\1$(cat tmp_ip) /" input_file
#ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 [win] #s1 127.0.0.1 #s2
```